# library not found when compiling with gcc on MacOS El capitan

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I have this problem when compiling with GCC on MacOSX El Capitan. I've already reinstall the Homebrew and GCC but I still can't compile even the simplest program. I have got no idea what is really happening in here:

```
 Koplo$ gcc test.c -o test
 ld: library not found for -lgcc
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.